# Counting the number of Excel attachments

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I download Excel files that I get e-mailed that meet a given criteria.

If there is no attachment, I need to scrape the body of the e-mail, and paste it into an Excel document.

How do I detect if I've been sent only non-Excel attachments - For example, if someone attaches a PDF.

I figured to count the number of attachments that contain the string ".xls", and if I have more than 0 results, process the downloads. Otherwise, scrape the e-mail body.

I've found:

1) How to count the attachments

```
oOlItm.Attachments.Count <> 0
```

2) How to check if any given attachment has a given string in it

```
(InStr(oOlAtch.FileName, ".xls") > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work:

```
For Each oOlItm In oOlAtch.attachments
    If InStr(1, oOlItm.filname, ".xls") > 1 Then cnt = cnt + 1
Next oOlItm 
if cnt > 0 then ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each oOlAtch In oOlItm.Attachments

            ExcelAttachmentNumber = 0

                 If (InStr(oOlAtch.FileName, ".xls") > 0) Then
                    ExcelAttachmentNumber = ExcelAttachmentNumber + 1
                    Else
                    End If
Next
```

Comment: The statement "ExcelAttachmentNumber = 0" needs to be outside the "For Each" loop. Your code will never count more than 1, and if the last attachment is not an .xls, you'll get 0.